Rolling count/tally between a list of values in a creative way
I have 2 DataFrames. The first is has a List of Dicts of values. The second has no data, but has a list of columns that are integers.
data1 = [{'Start': 51, 'End': 55},{'Start':24, 'End':37},{'Start':89,'End':122},{'Start':44, 'End':31}, {'Start':77, 'End':50}, {'Start':10, 'End':9}]
dfm1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)

data2 = [-40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
dfm2 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=data2)

Let's assume that data1 has 500 data points. My goal is that I want a tally of ranges of the differences in dfm1 based upon a variable sliding window size and I want that tally to exist in dfm2.
I want to create a sliding window of calculation of the difference between data1[index + window] - data1[index]. Then, based upon that difference between the values at the 2 indexes, I want to add a tally to dfm2 if it is less than or equal to the dfm1 column value, but not less than the column-1 value. We would assume that, in my example, column -40 would never ever have a tally greater than 0.
My desired date output, for the dfm1 values I provided, and we are tallying Start values, and a window of size 2 would be (for dfm2):
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

This would be performing 51-89 = -38, 24-44 = -20, 89-77=12, 44-10=34 for a window size of 2.  A window size of 3 would be 51-44, 24-77, and 89-10...
The cheap and easy way is obviously for me to iterate and create tallies.  But I know that DataFrame has some methods like rolling which may work really well for this.
What if I wanted to do this same rolling tally, but rather than subtracting Start from Start, what if I wanted to subtract an index's Start from its same End, and then perform that rolling tally based upon the difference from window_size away?
What if I didn't preset the column names in dfm2, and I let them be auto added as new tallies are discovered, say in ranges of 10?

1- not clear. 2- what have you tried? [ask] and [mre]

I know very little about DataFrame, so I haven't really tried anything.  I was looking for a good starting point, and I'm thankful someone spent the time to help.  I did not want to use a standard Python solution and just iterate through with a lambda or with normal list usage.

With rolling and the first part of the question:
def tally_differences(dfm1, dfm2, window_size):
    diff_df = dfm1['Start'].diff(window_size)

    bins = dfm2.columns.tolist() + [float('inf')]
    labels = dfm2.columns.tolist()
    tallies = pd.cut(diff_df, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False).value_counts()

    dfm2_updated = dfm2.copy()
    dfm2_updated.loc[0] = tallies

    return dfm2_updated


window_size = 2
dfm2_updated = tally_differences(dfm1, dfm2, window_size)
print(dfm2_updated)

Output:
   -40  -30  -20  -10   0    10   20   30   40
0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0

For your super boss mode, I don't know if I understood it well or not ( I hope someone edits your question text in a proper way ), but:
def tally_differences_easter_egg(dfm1, window_size):
    diff_df = dfm1['End'] - dfm1['Start']

    bins = pd.interval_range(start=diff_df.min()//10*10, end=diff_df.max()//10*10+10, freq=10, closed='left')
    tallies = pd.cut(diff_df.rolling(window_size).sum(), bins=bins).dropna().astype(str).value_counts()

    dfm2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=tallies.index)
    dfm2.loc[0] = tallies

    return dfm2

window_size = 2
dfm2_easter_egg = tally_differences_easter_egg(dfm1, window_size)
print(dfm2_easter_egg)

This will gave us:
   [10, 20)  [20, 30)  [-30, -20)
0         1         1           1


Can you explain the interval_range and the cut logic to me?  You did some wizardry.

pd.interval_range creates some intervals for us, the 10s are for creating the proper interval, and the pd.cut makes the bin values into discrete intervals. left and closed are also for determining the intervals are closed or open from which side. The two functions are allowing to create a range of intervals, based on the mins and maxes of the diff_df and then rolling sums into intervals.

OK.  I'm starting to understand.  Out of curiosity, why did you sum the rolling?  Does the diff_df initially contain a DataFrame of all possibilities?  I really like that solution, but don't quite understand what that data structure holds.  This is where I'm new to DataFrame.
